# Compilation errors on CGAL examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cgal, vcpkg

I'm trying to install CGAL on my computer following the official [guide](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html):

After having installed CGAL and Qt5 with vcpkg, I've generated the VS solution via CMake as described. But now I'm facing the following errors when trying to build the solution in VS:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Build started: Project: CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: adding_handles, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: colored_face, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: constrained, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: constrained_hierarchy_plus, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: constrained_plus, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: copy_triangulation_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>------ Build started: Project: for_loop_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Automatic MOC for target CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources
4>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
3>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
6>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
7>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
8>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
5>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
3>adding_handles.cpp
9>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
4>colored_face.cpp
7>constrained_plus.cpp
8>copy_triangulation_2.cpp
6>constrained_hierarchy_plus.cpp
9>for_loop_2.cpp
5>constrained.cpp
2>Generating ui_ImageInterface.h
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
2>mocs_compilation.cpp
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(23,46): error C2039:  'finite_face_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(11): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(24,5): error C2065:  'f': undeclared identifier
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(24,23): error C2039:  'blue': is not a member of 'CGAL'
4>C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2.h(32): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL'
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(24,27): error C3861:  'blue': identifier not found
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(28,22): error C2039:  'red': is not a member of 'CGAL'
4>C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2.h(32): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL'
4>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\colored_face.cpp(28,25): error C3861:  'red': identifier not found
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,24): error C2039:  'Finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,24): error C2039:         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,24): error C2039:         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,24): error C2039:             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,24): error C2039:         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,70): error C4430:  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(10,49): error C2146:  syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Finite_vertex_handles'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(16,49): error C2825:  'Finite_vertex_handles': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(16,32): error C2510:  'Finite_vertex_handles': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(16,79): error C4430:  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(16,49): error C2146:  syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Finite_vertex_handles_iterator'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(34,35): error C2825:  'Finite_vertex_handles': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
4>Done building project "colored_face.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
10>------ Build started: Project: hierarchy, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(34,26): error C2510:  'Finite_vertex_handles': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(35,42): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(35,42): error C2039:         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(35,42): error C2039:         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(35,42): error C2039:             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(35,42): error C2039:         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2100:  illegal indirection
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert from 'iterator' to 'CGAL::internal::CC_iterator<CGAL::Compact_container<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<GT,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<TDS2>>,CGAL::Default,CGAL::Default,CGAL::Default>,false>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:             GT=K,
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:             TDS2=CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): error C2440:         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(37,26): message :  No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(42,51): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(42,51): error C2039:         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(42,51): error C2039:         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(42,51): error C2039:             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(42,51): error C2039:         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void>>,CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<Gt,CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void>>>>'
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         with
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         [
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :             Gt=K
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(7): message :         ]
9>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\for_loop_2.cpp(43,18): error C2065:  'vh': undeclared identifier
9>Done building project "for_loop_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
11>------ Build started: Project: info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
10>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
5>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\constrained.cpp(25,42): error C2039:  'finite_edges': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Default,Itag>'
5>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\constrained.cpp(10): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,CGAL::Default,Itag>'
5>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\constrained.cpp(26,28): error C2065:  'e': undeclared identifier
11>info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.cpp
10>hierarchy.cpp
5>Done building project "constrained.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
12>------ Build started: Project: info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
12>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
12>info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.cpp
8>copy_triangulation_2.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\copy_triangulation_2.exe
6>constrained_hierarchy_plus.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\constrained_hierarchy_plus.exe
11>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.cpp(31,51): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
11>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.cpp(9): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
11>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.cpp(32,17): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
11>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.cpp(32,38): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
11>Done building project "info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
13>------ Build started: Project: info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
12>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.cpp(34,52): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Regular_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
12>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.cpp(13): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Regular_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
12>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.cpp(35,17): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
13>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
12>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.cpp(35,38): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
12>Done building project "info_insert_with_pair_iterator_regular_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
14>------ Build started: Project: info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
15>------ Build started: Project: polygon_triangulation, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
13>info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.cpp
2>qrc_CGAL.cpp
14>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
2>c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_CGAL.cpp': No such file or directory
2>qrc_Input.cpp
2>c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_Input.cpp': No such file or directory
2>qrc_File.cpp
2>c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_File.cpp': No such file or directory
2>qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp
2>c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp': No such file or directory
2>Generating Code...
15>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
14>info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp
15>polygon_triangulation.cpp
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(429,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2.
2>Done building project "CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
16>------ Build started: Project: draw_triangulation_2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
17>------ Build started: Project: polylines_triangulation, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
16>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
3>adding_handles.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\adding_handles.exe
17>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
16>draw_triangulation_2.cpp
17>polylines_triangulation.cpp
18>------ Build started: Project: print_cropped_voronoi, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
18>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
18>print_cropped_voronoi.cpp
10>hierarchy.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\hierarchy.exe
13>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.cpp(44,51): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
13>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.cpp(10): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
13>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.cpp(45,17): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(67,50): error C2039:  'all_face_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag>'
14>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp(44,51): error C2039:  'finite_vertex_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
14>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp(10): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds>'
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(24): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag>'
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(68,5): error C2065:  'f': undeclared identifier
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(108,49): error C2039:  'finite_face_handles': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag>'
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(24): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag>'
14>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp(45,17): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
15>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polygon_triangulation.cpp(110,10): error C2065:  'f': undeclared identifier
14>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp(45,32): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
15>Done building project "polygon_triangulation.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
19>------ Build started: Project: regular, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>constrained_plus.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\constrained_plus.exe
14>Done building project "info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
20>------ Build started: Project: terrain, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
19>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
20>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
19>regular.cpp
20>terrain.cpp
21>------ Build started: Project: terrain_with_info, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
21>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
21>terrain_with_info.cpp
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(22,58): error C2039:  'vertices_in_constraint': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(12): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(23,18): error C2065:  'vh': undeclared identifier
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(31,38): error C2039:  'subconstraints': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(12): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(32,24): error C2065:  'sc': undeclared identifier
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(32,45): error C2065:  'sc': undeclared identifier
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(37,56): error C2039:  'contexts': is not a member of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(12): message :  see declaration of 'CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT>'
17>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\polylines_triangulation.cpp(38,25): error C2065:  'c': undeclared identifier
22>------ Build started: Project: triangulation_prog1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
13>C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.cpp(45,32): error C2065:  'v': undeclared identifier
22>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
13>Done building project "info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
23>------ Build started: Project: voronoi, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
23>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexa/CGAL-5.0/examples/Triangulation_2/CMakeLists.txt
22>triangulation_prog1.cpp
23>voronoi.cpp
18>print_cropped_voronoi.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\print_cropped_voronoi.exe
17>Done building project "polylines_triangulation.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
20>terrain.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\terrain.exe
19>regular.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\regular.exe
21>terrain_with_info.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\terrain_with_info.exe
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.lib'
16>Done building project "draw_triangulation_2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
22>triangulation_prog1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\triangulation_prog1.exe
23>voronoi.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexa\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\Debug\voronoi.exe
24>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
24>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 12 succeeded, 11 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

I've noticed that vcpkg installs CGAL 4.14 but the examples I'm trying to compile are already 5.0. I've checked the 4.14 [manual](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14/Manual/installation.html) that states 4.14 should have the examples shipped with it. Sadly, the vcpkg version doesn't contain any examples and I can't find any online.

My question is: Am I missing something when installing CGAL with vcpkg? Am I doing something wrong in the compilation process in Visual Studio? Or where do I get the examples for 4.14 to compile and test? Or when do they update the vcpkg version of CGAL to 5.0?

Comment: The reason why you cannot find examples for previous CGAL versions is that the packaging changed in 5.0. Before that, there were no specific link to download only examples, but everyting (source code, examples, tests and demos) was in the same zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions :

- either you download the full CGAL 4.14 source code [from github](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/releases%2FCGAL-4.14.2), the examples are in it
- or you can upgrade your vcpkg so it downloads CGAL 5.0, by pulling master through git.